# Why should I use --user flag, is it a good practice?

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to upgrade pip and in some examples, I saw --user flag as in [here](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#linux-and-macos) indicating python3 -m pip install **--user** --upgrade pip. I have never used this flag before, and If I use it now, what would it change?

I read this article from the home page of [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs). It is still not clear to me, what is the benefit of this?

Comment: Yes it's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#alternate-installation-the-user-scheme):

> ### Alternate installation: the user scheme
>
> This scheme is designed to be the most convenient solution for users that don’t have write permission to the global site-packages directory or don’t want to install into it. It is enabled with a simple option:
>
> ```
> python setup.py install --user
> ```

As to "good practice", it depends. I personally install everything in virtual environments (using Poetry), so the exact set of packages and versions is reproducible on different machines.